# Why Mongodb config changes not getting applied?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I am running Mongodb on AWS windows instance, I changed my config setting as following:

```
net:
  port: 30000
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

As far as my knowledge, Server should get started on port 30000, it can listen request from other ip as well

However, on restarting mongod, it is still running on localhost and listening to port 27017

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you. What I did is a workaround it. I start the service with specifying the port and ip.

```
mongod --auth --port 30000 --dbpath /data/db --bind_ip_all
```